# Как принимать post запрос от php на python

Tags: php, python, telegram-bot, rest, telebot

Здравствуйте создаю телеграм ботов на python, мой знакомый предложил мне сделать бота для его сайта и сказал, что его код на php будет по curl отправлять post запрос мне на python ( там будет число )и мой бот должен иметь слушателя и принимать этот пост запрос и обробатывать... Такой вот вопрос что значит слушателя ( предпологаю что это что-то связанное с многопоточностью ) и как принимать пост запрос от php на python ?)

Comment: Это обычное API, берите любой фрейморк (FastAPI или Flask например), или работайте напрямую с requests

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я могу понять, вам не хватает знаний в области `http` и протоколов обмена данными.

`http` (как и `ws`, например) не зависит от того, кто и как отправил данные, они всегда приходят в одинаковой форме. И если вы на `php` отправили данные `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`, то не важно, кто их получит - `js`, `python` или сервер на плюсах, данные всегда будут одинаковые. Собстенно, протоколы и стандарты и нужны как раз для того, чтобы не думать, кто и как отдал данные, а кто и как их получил.

Второй вопрос - это то, как реализовать "слушателя". Если вы пишете на питоне, то у вас есть `django`, `flask`, `fastapi`. Для чего-то простого типа бота `django` излишен, так что я бы его в данном случае не советовал, а по моей субъектнивной оценке советовал бы `fastapi`.

Итого, чтобы решить данную задачу, вам нужно что-то типа

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

server = FastAPI()

@server.post('/api/smth_url/')
async def create_new_image(data):
    responce = await do_smth(data)
    return responce
```

Документация и куча статей в помощь :)